# Symfony mkdir(): File exists upload file in the server

Tags: symfony, file-upload, mkdir

I used my project in my local server it works but when i used it with an external server to upload a files i have this error 
"Warning: mkdir(): File exists " !  i can't create the directory i don't know why

Comment: which directory ? What happens if you try to create that directory on the operating system level ?

Comment: the directory that it will  contain the uploaded  files , a message error appear

Comment: I meant the name and depth / hierarchy of the directory

Answer (score 1):

I think mkdir is not recursive by default, try using the filesystem component, which avoid you having this kind of issues: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem/introduction.html

Comment: how can i use it exactly !  ,  i have checked it , he is installed

Comment: Just follow the link, all is explained there